# GridView doesn't refresh LINQ to XML data?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, linq-to-xml

If have a Xml-file with 3 entries

Country Name="Denmark" InternetTLD="dk"

Country Name="Holland" InternetTLD="nl"

Country Name="Greate britain" InternetTLD="uk"

In my web-page if have a textbox, gridview and xmlDataSource.
When I don't specify anything in the textbox then all three countries are are loaded using a LINQ query into the xmlDataSource and then displayed in the gridview. 
But when I specify for example 'Denmark' in the textbox then I keep on seeing all 3 records whereas the count property of the LINQ query says 1 and the Data-property of the xmlDataSource shows only 1 country as well (Denmark) as it should be.

Problem is that the gridView doesn't seem to refresh the new data???

Here's my code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        QueryXml();
    }  // Page_Load()


    private void QueryXml()
    {
        XElement _countries = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath(COUNTRIES_XML));
        IEnumerable<XElement> query = null;

        // extract all countries
        if (txtCountry.Text == "" || txtCountry.Text == "*")
        {
            query = from c in _countries.Elements()
                    select c;
        }
        else
        {
            // Extract all elements where Name has been specified
            query = from c in _countries.Elements()
                    where c.Attribute("Name").Value.ToString().StartsWith(txtCountry.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                    select c;
        }

        // Set xml filtered string data source
        xmlDsCountries.Data =
            "<Countries>" +
            string.Join("", query.Select(country => country.ToString())) +
            "</Countries>";
        // set the data source of the gridview
        gdvwCountries.DataSource = xmlDsCountries;
        // Show the data
        gdvwCountries.DataBind();

        lblMsg.Text = query.Count().ToString();
    }  // QueryXml()
```

Why isn't the gridView refreshing?

thank you

Chris

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off caching on the XmlDataSource

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    xmlDsCountries.EnableCaching = false;
    //...........the rest.............
}
```